# How to store return value from $system("...") call in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

If I simulate the following module:

```
module test;

    longint seconds;
    initial begin
        seconds = $system("date +%s");
        $display("Seconds: %0d", seconds);
        $finish;
    end

endmodule
```

The output from both `ncsim` and `vsim` is:

```
1571172006
Seconds: 0
```

So I can see that the `$system` call *is* printing the time in seconds `1571172006`, however the variable `seconds` has a value of `0` so I'm not saving that value.

Is there a way for me to save that value? (Preferably not using DPI)

Thanks in advance.

[edaplayground link](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/dR5)

Comment: You don't want to store the return value. You want to capture what the command printed to `stdout`. The return value (i.e. the exit code) will be `0` to indicate command success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's horrible, but you can pipe the output of your linux command into a file and then read the file:

```
$system("date +%s | tee date.txt");
fd = $fopen("date.txt","r");
count=($fgets(s, fd) == 0);        assert(count == 0);
count=($sscanf(s,"%d", seconds));  assert(count == 1);
$display("Seconds: %0d", seconds);
```

---

```
module test;

  longint seconds;
  initial begin
    int fd;
    int count;
    string s;
    $system("date +%s | tee date.txt");
    fd = $fopen("date.txt","r");
    count=($fgets(s, fd) == 0);        assert(count == 0);
    count=($sscanf(s,"%d", seconds));  assert(count == 1);
    $display("Seconds: %0d", seconds);
    $finish;
  end

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4R5e

Comment: Upvote for a solution! I'll leave the question open in case there are any cleaner solutions, but I do appreciate your answer. I get an assertion failure on `count != 0` though -- I'm not sure why.

Comment: @CharlesClayton Fixed here, but not on EDA Playground as I have switched off my laptop for the night. The curse of the last minute edit.

Comment: @CharlesClayton Fixed on EDA Playground, too.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why you wouldn't want to use the DPI. Much simpler than Matthew's approach.

```
module test;
  import "DPI-C" function longint date();
    longint seconds;
    initial begin
      seconds = date();
        $display("Seconds: %0d", seconds);
        $finish;
    end

endmodule

#include <time.h>
long int date() {
  return time(NULL);
}
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5NTw